# Laravel call Cache::tags::put. Do I have to call Cache::tags::flush to flush out expired data in standard_ref

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, redis-cache

Run

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    Cache::tags('test')->put('test_' . Str::random(), time(), 60);
}
```

**first see Redis db**
[image]

**after 60s ttl**
[image]

standard_ref Members not removed

Do I have to call Cache::tags::flush to flush out expired data in standard_ref?

I don't think it's good

```
Cache::tags('test')->flush();
```

[image]

Comment: The problem started when I used JWT

Comment: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth JWTGuard::logout https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/0e7b35c4f25fcdc7bc02e49966e41c9ee67b2ff1/src/JWTGuard.php#L150

Comment: Redis Set `standard_ref` has 1000W members, causing Redis to run out of memory